# TypeError when I use Typescript with VueJS

Tags: typescript, vue.js, typeerror

I try to start using typescript with VueJS but I encounter a TypeError problem.

In my App.vue, I have a array of Gallery class as a class property.
In the created hook, I call a webservice to fill this array.
Once I fill it, when I log it, I have Objects and not Gallery instances. And if I try to call a function on a Gallery instance, it fails.
I think the problem is more a TS problem than a Vue problem.

I can't understand why I have actually an array of Object when I say everywhere I need an array of Gallery.

If anyone has a idea to help me, I'm more than interrested.

Thanks for reading. I paste you all my code below.

Have a nice day ;)

Dimitri

**App.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <CvGallery v-for="(gallery, i) in galleries" gallery="gallery" :key="i"></CvGallery>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
    import CvGallery from "@/components/CvGallery.vue";
    import Gallery from "@/models/Gallery";
    import axios from "@/axios/axios-creatiview"

    @Component({
        components: {
            CvGallery
        },
    })
    export default class App extends Vue {
        private galleries: Gallery[] = [];

        created() {
            axios.get('').then(response => {
                console.log(response.data);
                response.data.forEach((galleryJson: {id: number; name: string; description: string}) => {
                    const gallery = new Gallery(galleryJson.id, galleryJson.name, galleryJson.description);
                    this.galleries.push(gallery);
                    console.log(typeof gallery);
                });
            });
        }
    }
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

**Gallery.ts**

```
export default class Gallery{
    private readonly id: number;
    private readonly name: string;
    private readonly description: string;

    constructor(id: number, name: string, description: string) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }

    getId(){
        return this.id;
    }

    getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    getDescription(){
        return this.description;
    }
}
```

**CvGallery.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="gallery">
        <p>Gallery</p>
        <p>{{ gallery.getDescription() }}</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import {Component, Vue, Prop} from 'vue-property-decorator'
    import Gallery from "@/models/Gallery";
    @Component
    export default class CvGallery extends Vue{
        @Prop() private gallery!: Gallery;
    }
</script>

<style scoped>
    .gallery{
        background-color: #222222;
        color: #DDDDDD;
    }
</style>
```

**log**

```
16:16:42,658 [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS... log.js:24
16:16:42,771
(3) […]
​
0: Object { id: 1, name: "DisneyWorld", description: "First trip to DisneyWorld Florida!" }
​
1: Object { id: 2, name: "Europapark", description: "The best German park" }
​
2: Object { id: 3, name: "Disneyland Paris", description: "A lot of walkthrough attractions" }
​
length: 3
​
<prototype>: Array []
App.vue:23
16:16:42,772 object 3 App.vue:27
16:16:42,774 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: _vm.gallery.getDescription is not a function"

found in

---> <CvGallery> at src/components/CvGallery.vue
       <App> at src/App.vue
         <Root> vue.runtime.esm.js:619
16:16:42,774 TypeError: "_vm.gallery.getDescription is not a function"
    render CvGallery.vue:7
    VueJS 20
vue.runtime.esm.js:1888
16:16:42,775 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: _vm.gallery.getDescription is not a function"

found in

---> <CvGallery> at src/components/CvGallery.vue
       <App> at src/App.vue
         <Root> vue.runtime.esm.js:619
16:16:42,775 TypeError: "_vm.gallery.getDescription is not a function"
    render CvGallery.vue:7
    VueJS 20
vue.runtime.esm.js:1888
16:16:42,776 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: _vm.gallery.getDescription is not a function"

found in

---> <CvGallery> at src/components/CvGallery.vue
       <App> at src/App.vue
         <Root> vue.runtime.esm.js:619
16:16:42,776 TypeError: "_vm.gallery.getDescription is not a function"
    render CvGallery.vue:7
    VueJS 20
vue.runtime.esm.js:1888
```

Comment: Try decorating your container div with `v-if` like this : `<div v-if="galleries">
        <CvGallery....>
    </div>` Since your data loaded async it will be empty when your view created initially.

Comment: Please, include the error as text. The problem should be intelligible without navigating to external links and doesn't require to be represented as an image.

Comment: @Eldar I try but it changes nothing. I think Vue logic is ok because my "galleries" class property is reactive. Also, in the error stack, we have the same error 3 times, like the number of elements of my array.
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @EstusFlask Yep sorry I just didn't know how to makes this clear. After your comment, I discover there is a right click option in firefox console to do that. I will not forget next time thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not TypeScript problem because the error occurs at runtime, it would be the same in JavaScript.

`vm.gallery.getDescription is not a function` error means that `gallery` is defined, otherwise it would be `Cannot read property 'getDescription' of undefined`. It also means that `gallery` is not an instance of `Gallery`, otherwise there would be `getDescription` method.

Since there are no mistakes in `created` hook, the problem can be narrowed down to how `gallery` is passed to the component; it's a string value:

```
<CvGallery v-for="(gallery, i) in galleries" gallery="gallery" :key="i"></CvGallery>
```

Instead, it should be bound:

```
<CvGallery v-for="(gallery, i) in galleries" :gallery="gallery" :key="i"></CvGallery>
```

Comment: You're welcome, glad it was that simple. Also, this is TS problem, in a way. The problem is that vue-property-decorator doesn't provide proper props typing features and requires to be asserted with `gallery!: Gallery`. If it were possible for typing system to determine that `gallery` prop is a string and not Gallery, the problem could be revealed at compilation time. FWIW, Vue class components were abandoned, for properly typed TS check function components and composition API, https://vue-composition-api-rfc.netlify.com/api.html#definecomponent

Comment: Nice thanks for the complementary ansmwer. I gonna search and chage my code in that way. It's true that I'm asking me "why Am I using TS if it can't tell me when I'm giving the wrong type..."